# AngularJS how to change ng-model binding to another element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How to dynamically rebind elements with ng-model (change ng-model subject)

For example I have

```
<input type="text" ng-model="info">
<input type="text">
```

But after some user interactions I want to modify it to

```
<input type="text" ng-model="info">
<input type="text" ng-model="info">
```

or other variables. Any ideas how to do that dynamically?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? Seems very un-Angular-y... What's the overall problem?

Comment: What is the use case? Seems trivial to use 2 ng-model and some controller logic and perhaps some event binding

Comment: These are complex dynamically constructed forms that comes from data.

Comment: For example there is a form with elements and user loads JSON object into the form. Then he can dynamically bind fields one to another and fields to attributes for that JSON object so that they would match his own needs.

Comment: The question is trivial when it's up to two input fields - we just bind them to objects (obj1.field and obj2.field) and when we want to have the same value - we do just `$scope.obj1 = $scope.obj2;` - but that's the trivial case/

Comment: something doesn't make sense here.  can you add some additional information to clarify what your actual problem is?  I pretty much say this on at least one angular question a day;  There are only very rare edge cases where modifying the DOM is necessary, and those cases can almost always be isolated to a directive.

Comment: since you mention forms and JSON, I'm wondering if maybe you aren't talking about JSON schema.  There is already a directive suite that handles JSON schema in angular, http://schemaform.io/.  I think it supports dynamic form changes, but even if it doesn't, examining their code will likely give you a better understanding of the overall process if you want to roll your own framework for this, which is much too broad of a topic to cover in one question/answer here.

Comment: another really powerful form module that uses a json model is [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/). lots and lots of options, validation and good docs

Answer (score 1):

Then make it as Array.

In controller

```
$scope.info = [];
```

In html dynamically

```
<input type="text" ng-model="info[$index]">
```